# Caso não conste a opção, como repetir a pergunta em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para repetir a questão acima em caso de a resposta não obter nenhuma das opções dentro da função `if` e `elif`?

```
parcelax = int(input('Qual formato de parcelamento?  \n 1) Á Vista \n 2) 12x  \n 3) 30x \n 4) 60x  \n'))
valor1 = 1
if (parcelax == 1):
    valor1 = valor
elif (parcelax == 2):
    valor1 = valor / 12
elif (parcelax == 3):
    valor1 = valor / 30
elif (parcelax == 4):
    valor1 = valor / 60
else:
    print('Digito incorreto!\n Digite valor Valido!')
print('Valor de parcela até o momento é de: R${:.2f}!'.format(valor1))
```

e estou fazendo o post pois ja fiz inumeras procuras e nenhuma delas consegui achar uma solução para meu caso em especifico.

Comment: Seu caso não é tão específico assim e a pergunta marcada responde o que você precisa: se quer ler a entrada do usuário enquanto não for um valor válido, basta fazer um laço de repetição infinito. Estude sobre as estruturas de repetição do Python, seja o `while` ou `for` e tente implementar no seu código. Se ainda assim não conseguir, pode voltar, [edit] a pergunta e demonstrar porque sua pergunta seria diferente das demais existentes. Não é só porque é um trecho de código diferente que o problema é diferente.

Comment: estudei as estruturas de repetição while, e até tentei fazer por meio de if - else, porém da erro de sintaxe de todas as maneiras e eu nem se quer sei no que estou errando, reescrevo todo o código, toda a vez, por isso vim aqui tirar a duvida de por onde estou errando ou se estou utilizando de maneira incorreta, mas é isso, se minha pergunta vai ser marcada como duplicada, só agradeço.